# Как правильно составить запрос MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть база данных. В ней 2 таблицы "wallets" и "orders". Мне нужно выбрать кошелек из таблицы "wallets" у которого month_limit  + сумма которую задал юзер <= 10000, и этот же кошелек нужно проверить в таблице "orders" может быть он уже там лежит и не один раз и ожидает оплаты, взять все строки с этим кошельком из "orders" и их суммы добавить к month_limit  + сумма которую задал юзер <= 10000. Посоветуйте как лучше здесь поступить, можно ли это сделать все в одном запросе, или нужно в первом запросе выбрать все кошельки из "wallets" а во втором проверить их наличие в таблице "orders" и проверить значение не больше ли 10000?

Comment: Вам нужно что бы общая сумма (limit+user_input+sum(orders)) не превышала 10000. Или вывести все где limit+user<10000 но в каждой строке показать эту сумму плюс сумму из orders ?

Comment: И не пишите в вопросе "_можно ли это сделать в одном запросе_", практически все можно сделать одним запросом :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вывести все кошельки где month_limit+$user_sum и при этом показать еще и эту сумму плюс сумму из orders, то:

```
SELECT w.*,
       (SELECT w.month_limit + $user_sum + COALESCE(SUM(o.sum_to_buyer),0)
          FROM orders o
         WHERE w.idwallets = o.wallets_idwallets
       ) as total_sum
  FROM wallets AS w
 WHERE month_limit + $user_sum <= 10000
```

Если отобрать, где общая сумма, включая orders, меньше 10к, то немного усложнаем добавляя внешний запрос и проверку на общую сумму:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT w.*,
           (SELECT w.month_limit + $user_sum + COALESCE(SUM(o.sum_to_buyer),0)
              FROM orders o
             WHERE w.idwallets = o.wallets_idwallets
           ) as total_sum
      FROM wallets AS w
     WHERE month_limit + $user_sum <= 10000
   ) A
 WHERE total_sum<=10000
```

Comment: Второй запрос выдает ошибку Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias
 , а он то мне и нужен

Comment: @rodgers Опять буковку забыл. Исправил. Там буква A теперь появилась после закрывающейся скобки :)

Comment: @rodgers Когда задаете вопросы по SQL старайтесь структуру таблиц не в виде фоток выкладывать, а текстом, причем прямо в виде SQL`create table`. Если таблицы создать легко я всегда ответы проверяю перед тем как выложить и досадных описок не бывает.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: можно вопрос а буква "А" которую ты добавил, это псевдоним для выборки получился так?

Comment: @rodgers Да, именно так. при желании можно по нему обращаться кажем в where. А MySQL чуть ли не единственная из баз в которой подзапросы в from без алиаса не работают, вот и забываю их вечно, если для логики не нужны :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно одним запросом через `JOIN`:

```
SELECT w.* FROM wallets AS w JOIN orders AS o ON w.idwallets = o.wallets_idwallets HAVING SUM(o.sum_to_buyer) + w.month_limit + $user_sum <= 10000
```

Как я понял, сумма в orders - это поле sum_to_buyer.

В переменной $user_sum лежит сумма, веденная пользователем.

Comment: Функцию SUM нельзя применять в where

Comment: Выдает ошибку "Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function"

Comment: тогда HAVING нужно